# Exponential trigonometrical equation

Tags: trigonometry

Find $x$ from $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ in:  $$2^{\sin 3x}-8^{\sin x}=\sin^3{x}$$ 
I know that $x=0$ verifies the equation, but is it the only solution?

Comment: $8^{\sin x} = 2^{(3\sin x)}$, so compare $\sin 3x$ to $3\sin x$ and see what happens.

Comment: Blue , thank you,I managed to solve it now :)

Comment: Good to know! You should write-up your solution as an answer here and accept it, so that your question doesn't keep getting bumped into the Unanswered list.

Answer (score 2):

If $2^{\sin{3x}}\gt2^{3\sin x} \iff 4\sin^3{x}\lt 0 \iff \sin^3{x}\lt0$ wich is in contradiction with 
$2^{\sin{3x}}-2^{3\sin x}\gt0$ . It is proved equivalently that for $2^{\sin{3x}}\lt 2^{3\sin x} \iff \sin x\gt0$ so the equation doesn't have solutions.Finally,the only solution is $\sin{x}=0 \iff x=0$

Comment: The prose (and $\TeX$) could use a little tweaking, but the logic is sound. Embarrassingly, I hadn't initially thought of using the triple-angle formula ---in my head I was using Calculus to compare the trig functions--- but it comes in handy here. To save face, I'm going to post a "one-line" version of your argument, but I still think you should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), $\operatorname{sgn}$, we can compress @Andrew's argument thusly:
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{sgn}\left( 2^{\sin 3x} - 2^{3\sin x} \right) 
&= \phantom{-}\operatorname{sgn}\left( \sin 3x - 3 \sin x \right) \\
&= \phantom{-}\operatorname{sgn}\left( - 4 \sin^3 x \right) \\
&= -\operatorname{sgn}\left( \sin^3 x \right)
\end{align}$$
so the left-hand and right-hand sides of the original equation match only when they vanish, which happens at (and only at*) $x=0$.

*Over the given domain.